# VFS: Cannot open root device mmcblk1p1 or unknown-block(179,33)

Tags: linux-kernel, sd-card, root-filesystem

I am trying to run Linux on custom board based on Nvidia TK1. When I try to boot the board from SD card, I get following error:

```
VFS: Cannot open root device "mmcblk1p1" or unknown-block(179,33): error -30
Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions:
 b300        30539776 mmcblk0  driver: mmcblk
   b301        14680064 mmcblk0p1 7369c667-ff51-ec4a-29cd-baaba3cee346
   b302            4096 mmcblk0p2 f854c27c-e81b-8de7-765a-2e9442bfc99a
   b303           65536 mmcblk0p3 b70d3266-5831-5aa3-255d-051742ea5ed4
   b304            4096 mmcblk0p4 c6cdb2ab-b49b-1154-0e82-7441842bdc87
   b305            4096 mmcblk0p5 a13ee970-e141-67fc-3e01-7e97dcea6b96
   b306            4096 mmcblk0p6 2a5c388f-b0ec-fb3b-32af-3c554123db5c
   b307            4096 mmcblk0p7 43fe1a02-fafb-3aaa-fb29-d1e85fa37c94
   b308            2048 mmcblk0p8 61bed875-f989-bb5c-a899-0f9573eff1b3
   b309          571392 mmcblk0p9 00f7ef05-a1e9-e53a-ca0b-cbd3493164bd
 b310            4096 mmcblk0rpmb  (driver?)
 b320        15558144 mmcblk1  driver: mmcblk
   b321        15557103 mmcblk1p1 5d52e9ff-6261-41c9-9816-73affe28b267
 Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(179,33)
```

I have made sure that the kernel is being supplied with correct root variable i.e `root=/dev/mmcblk1p1 rw`. I have also made sure that the card is properly formatted & is not read-only.

I even tried to look in the kernel source for `error -30` but couldn't find the function definition of `sys_mount()` which is returning this error.

Can someone point out the reason why this must be occurring? Thanks.

Comment: it might be similar to [this](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Embedded-Linux/Not-able-to-mount-root-fs-during-SD-boot-on-ZedBoard-Petalinux/td-p/851650) problem on Xilinx Zynq platform - the SD card controller write-protect pin is not connected so you have to disable the write protect code in the driver ... locate the entry for the SD card controller in your device tree and add the `disable-wp;` option to the node and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Yes I have checked from schematic and the write-protect pin is NC. I will try to add the disable-wp property in device tree and update status here. Thanks

Comment: @MurrayJensen I was able to disable write-protect functionality by modifying sdhci controller source code as adding disable-wp to device tree was not working.

Comment: Yes it depends whether the device driver supports disable-wp or not. I believe the mmc driver in Xilinx kernel does. You should look at whether you can connect the write-protect pin to an i/o port rather than just disabling wp, if you have the ability to change the hardware design - driver is likely to support this already...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this literally a full-size SD card?  Does the card have an RW switch in the "read-only" position?

https://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1102/~/sd%2Fsdhc%2Fsdxc-memory-card-is-write-protected-or-locked

The RW switch is enforced by the reader, not the card, so it could also be a hardware (or driver?) problem.

---

The error return from the mount system call should be an `errno` value.  Assuming the minus sign is just a convention -

```
 #define    EROFS   30  /* Read-only file system */
```

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.20/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/errno-base.h#L34

> I ... couldn't find the function definition of `sys_mount()` which is returning this error.

Yes, it's a pain.  The definition doesn't show up in [elixir search](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/ident/sys_mount) either.  System calls are defined using a macro:

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE5(mount, char __user *, dev_name, char __user *, dir_name,
                char __user *, type, unsigned long, flags, void __user *, data)
{
        return ksys_mount(dev_name, dir_name, type, flags, data);
}
```

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.20/source/fs/namespace.c#L3028

Comment: Its a 16 GB card with a single partition covering whole card. I have tried multiple cards but same result & its a micro SD card so there's no switch on it. Is there any setting about setting card to read-only mode in dtb files?

Comment: @arshan I don't know, though I would guess not.  Please edit the question with this additional information.

Comment: Thanks. +1 for the error code and function definition of sys_mount()

Comment: I was able to disable write-protect functionality in sdhci controller driver as pointed out by you. Thanks